# can a Type One diabetic fast?

Tags: sawm

I have type 1 diabetes which was diagnosed in november 2013, till last year I used to fast but I cannot now, because I have to take insulin during day times (i.e while fasting) and dinner and have to eat for every 2.5 hours. Is my fast excused?

Answer (score 3):

Health is also in the conditions where fast is excused. The conditions are

1. Health
2. When you're in a journey

But if you do not fast then you have to manage for a poor person to fast. Meaning you have to make all the arrangement for him like in *Sehri* and *Iftar*. After that your fast is excused but when you became healthy then the number of fast you excused you have to do then.

Sources: [Islamic Academy](http://www.islamicacademy.org/html/Books/GLIS/fgf.htm), [Ala-Hazrat](http://www.alahazrat.net/islam/roza-%28fasting%29-qanoon-e-shariat.php), [Islamic Society of Rutgers University](http://www.eden.rutgers.edu/~muslims/fasting.htm)

---

*By poor person mentioned here are those people who cannot manage food for their sehri and iftar*

Comment: Great answer, note that answers here are expected to provide a reference. Can you do that?

Comment: See the answer now, maybe it's okay now

Comment: thanks alottt brother. may allah bless the whole ummah.jazakallah khairan